# To implement richfaces tree table

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a requirement to implement tree table component using richfaces which should be similar to that present in [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/basic.xhtml) or in [openfaces](http://openfaces.org/demo/treetable/TreeTable_basicFeatures.jsf).Richfaces only has tree component.I don't have provisions to use primefaces or any other JSF libraries other than richfaces.At most I can use javascript or jquery tweaks.

Can someone please give an idea how to proceed to implement this.

Comment: So instead of spending 2 hours incorporating PrimeFaces or OpenFaces (and maybe some hours to tweak css), they require you to spend many , many hours... But your next best shot is to look for a jquery treetable like this and tweak it and try to get it jsf compliant (also CSS!)

Comment: @Kukeltje,Thanks for your input.Can you please name the jquery treetable library which I can use

Comment: hmmm I posted this in comment afaik but it somehow got lost, but Google is your friend. I never used one (I **am** allowed to use PrimeFaces), so any link I post would not be substantiated by any real experience with it, so you better investigate yourself

Comment: Once again thank you :)

Comment: Or maybe it is easier to use http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/tree (you ARE allowed to use omnifaces are you? if not ask the CEO to fire the one that is blocking this). You can create a table, create a thead and have the omnifaces tree populate the tbody. You only need to create event handlers in jquery to open/close the nodes I think

Comment: You are right. I am again going to discuss about these easier alternatives  with my lead today. Still if they don't agree then it's his problem :)